# How to point to generic abstract class?

Tags: c#, oop, class, inheritance, generics

I haven't got problems with code since my last problem with interface covariance. Today I took another approach to the OLGAtherer architecture and I found huge (for me) obstacle. I hope that its huge only for me and I will find answer here :) OK, please check this out:

I have abstract generic class:

```
abstract class Repository<T> where T : Entity
```

this class contain signatures of four CRUD methods (add, insert, etc.) and two protected fields. Any repository that I will create must inherit from this superclass. I have repositories like, for example:

```
class BookRepository : Repository<Book>
```

Now I have class DB that is responsible for operations on DB file. And there is my problem. Look at this method placed in DB class:

```
    void Add(List<Entity> enitites, Type entityType)
    {
       Repository<entityType> repo = EntitiesFactory(entityType);
       repo.Add(entities);
    }
```

I know that above method won't work, but this visualize my problem (hopefully) - I would like to dynamically create repository of the specified type, but I have no idea how to do this. This has been always my main OOP problem - I could code inheritance (or implementation of interfaces) but I could not use these inherited classes. Please clarify this to me. Thank you in advance.

Paweł

---

I used hints that you provided and this is what I have now:

```
public void Add<T>(List<T> entities, string repoName) where T : Entity
{
   Repository<T> repo = RepoFactory<T>(repoName, typeof(T));
   repo.Add(entities);
}

private Repository<T> RepoFactory<T>(string repoName, Type t) where T : Entity
{
   if (t == typeof(Book))
   {
   Repository<T> repo = (Repository<T>)((object)(new BookRepository(this.ConnectionString, repoName)));
   }

   return null;
```

}

RepoFactory is now in DB class (which is, by the way, some sort of Bridge here) - it should be moved elsewhere probably, but it's not a main problem here.

First, I don't know whether RepoFactory body is implemented in the proper way - I guess not.

Second - I assume that I will call DB methods from other class (let's say - WindowsForm, for simplicity). I will call Add with parameter T dependent on user's choice. This is situation that I have problem and fix it temporarily, because now DB is OK, but if I would have to implement WindowsForm code, I will encounter it another time (I think) - in the future I will try to figure out answer to the same question, but on the higher level (above DB) - I hope you understand me...
I basically mean, that I will not know how to dynamically call Add method, because T will be dependent on user's choice (OLGAtherer has to be Repository Manager that would support Books and other kind of collections). And if user will try to work with his book collection, I will have to call Add() method. If with Comics collection, Add(). I don't want to write class above for each kind of collection, but rather use one call of Add to do this.

If you understand what I mean, you're really good :) My English sucks, but I'm working on it.
Thank you for previous answers and thanks in advance for further ones.
Paweł

Comment: Hmmm, I think you're trying to reinvent the wheel. Why would you write your own ORM when there's plenty of well-developed alternatives like NHibernate and Linq2Sql already available?

Comment: `DB` sounds like a God object and `EntitiesFactory` sounds like a service locator. You are setting yourself up for an unmaintainable, untestable disaster.

Comment: Hello, I know that this may look like not a good idea - I'm still learning and I know that mastering of OOP will take a years. But if you would take a look at my code placed on Sourceforge I think that you would accept architecture that I've created yet. Thank you for response anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want. Will this do?

```
void Add<T>(List<T> entities) where T : Entity
{
   Repository<T> repo = EntitiesFactory(typeof(T));
   repo.Add(entities);
}
```

Also, I suggest that you be as flexible as possible with input parameters, e.g. use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>` for this method and also in the `Repository<T>.Add()` method. You might want to pass in a lazily-evaluated query, or chain multiple LINQ methods together.

Comment: WOW. Any time that I have no idea what to do and I cannot find answer anywhere, I know that I may post here and I will certainly get the answer! Thank you for that and for these useful hints about loosing dependencies. I'd like to ask you to read my new post below - there is next part of this question :) Best regards, Paweł

Answer (score 3):

You can make the `Add` method generic.

```
void Add<T>(List<T> enitites)
{
   Repository<T> repo = EntitiesFactory(typeof(T));
   repo.Add(entities);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make it type-safe by modifying your object hiearchy with one more layer of indirection as follows:

```
public abstract class EntityCollection<T> : List<T>
    where T : Entity
{
    public abstract Repository<T> GetRepository();
}

public class BookCollection : EntityCollection<Book>
{
    public override Repository<Book> GetRepository()
    {
        return BookRepository();
    }
}
```

So now you can modify your DB class as follows:

```
public void Add<T>(EntityCollection<T> entities)
{
    Repository<T> repo = entities.GetRepository();
    repo.Add(entities);
}
```

So now you can pass an instance of `BookCollection` into your `Add` method and it will work in a 100% type-safe, transparent manner.

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly the answer you're looking for, but its better to keep it type safe than to rely heavily on casts and type testing. If you have to switch on a generic type param, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Juliet, what you're saying is surely right, but actually I asked question above because I don't know how to not switch. It would be nice if you would tell me what to do not to use switch.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to everyone else's answers, you may want to take a look at the Inversion of Control (IoC) design pattern as well.  It may simplify your life in future work.

With dependency injection, which is what IoC gives you, you can significantly simplify your use of the EntitiesFactory, for example.

I'm using [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/index.html) at the moment to implement IoC and it's working well for me.

Here's [Martin Fowler's](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) page on IoC, and [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I'm very glad that I get so many useful informations here.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are returning in `EntitiesFactory()` is what you need to use. So the problem is really with code which you have not shown. Show the code for `EntitiesFactory()` and we get a better idea on what you are trying to accomplish.

NOTE: You understand that you cannot overload return types (unfortunately).

Comment: Unfortunately code that I wrote in Add method above is some sort of "pseudo code". I mean that this is how I would like to work :) Please read post below. Thank you for answer anyway.